# Добавить Title по умолчанию при создании ссылок в редакторе записей Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как сделать, чтобы при добавлении ссылок в редакторе записей Wordpress при нажатии на кнопку link, вместо ссылок типа:

How to make when adding links in the Wordpress post editor when clicking on the link button, instead of links like:

```
<a href="https://ссылка/">Текст1</a>
```

Добавлялись ссылки вида

Added links of the following type

```
<a title="Текст по умолчанию Текст1" href="https://ссылка/">Текст1</a>
```

Текст1 должен автоматически добавляться в конец атрибута title (title="Текст по умолчанию "), через пробел.

Text1 should be automatically added to the end of the title attribute (title="Текст по умолчанию "), separated by a space.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19292/automatically-add-title-attribute-to-links-in-wordpress

Comment: I don't need to automatically add title to all links, only when I add them in the post editor. Мне не нужно автоматически добавлять title во все ссылки, только когда я их добавляю в редакторе записей